# unable to sign up with json devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, curl, devise

I have a problem with Devise registration using /users/sign_up. I have to pass the registration details via rails terminal using curl like this:

```
curl: //your-domain:3000/users/sign_up --data "email=jump@gmail.com&password=123456789&password_confirmation=123456789"
```

and it should return:

```
{"success":true,"info":"Registered","email":"jump@example.com","auth_token":"N8N5MPqFNdDz3G1jRsC9"}
```

But I am getting below error message:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/users/sign_up"):
```

While users/sign_in is working perfectly:

```
curl: //your-domain:3000/users/sign_in.json --data "email=abc@gmail.com&password=123456789"
```

return:

```
{"success":true,"info":"Logged in","auth_token":"czzBpiNS7mkkQJAbHyMo","email":"abc@gmail.com"}
```

---

Below is my  RegistrationsController class:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:create], :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
  respond_to :json

  prepend_view_path 'app/views/devise'

  def create
    build_resource
    if resource.save
      sign_in resource
      resource.ensure_authentication_token!
      render :status => 200,
             :json => { :success => true,
                        :info => "Registered",
                        :email => resource.email,
                        :auth_token => resource.authentication_token }
    else
      render :status => :unprocessable_entity,
             :json => { :`enter code here`success => false,
                        :info => resource.errors }
    end
  end

end
```

---

and routes.rb: has following settings:

```
 devise_for(:users, :controllers => { :sessions => "sessions", :registrations => 'registrations' })
```

Comment: Can you show a dump of your `rake routes`?

Comment: I get below error when I use rake routes to get the dump.This is because of rake verion.


rake aborted!
You have already activated rake 10.1.1, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.0.3.

Comment: Have you just updated your gems? Will mean you've got a gem which is dependent on Rake `10.0.3`, but you're running Rails `4.0.2` or something

Comment: I am using gem 'rails', '3.2.11'. I think this won't be a problem. The problem is with Devise. If I am able to sign_in using json then why i can't do the same with sign_up. I don't know what is wrong with sign_up. I am stuck and can't go forward.I am using android app for passing sign_in and sign_up details. /users/sign_in is working well but /users/sign_up is creating problem.

Comment: Hmmmm. I can post code we use for this if you want? It's a little old, but should give some ideas on what may be the issue

Comment: That would of great help.

Comment: In the browser when i go to //your-domain/users/sign_in.json I get
{"email":"","password":null}
and when I go to //your-domain/users/sign_up.json I get
{"created_at":null,"email":"","id":null,"updated_at":null}
it should return something like this:
{"email":"","password":null,"password_confirmation:null"}
sign-up has problem in getting the page as json.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what we use (check it at http://firststopcosmeticshop.co.uk -- "register" @ top)

```
 class RegistrationsController < DeviseController
  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [ :new, :create, :cancel ]
  prepend_before_filter :authenticate_scope!, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters

  prepend_view_path 'app/views/devise'

  # GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
    build_resource({})
    respond_with self.resource
  end

  # POST /resource
  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    if resource.save
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource

      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :json => resource.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        format.html { respond_with resource }
      end
    end
  end
  ....
```

---

**Paths**

I think your error is from your devise paths (trying to send a POST request to `/sign_up`). You can see [the method should be `create` here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters):

> sign_up (Devise::RegistrationsController#create) - Permits
>   authentication keys plus password and password_confirmation

Why don't you try this in your config/routes.rb file:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "sessions", registrations: "registrations"}, path_names: { sign_in: 'sign_in', password: 'forgot', confirmation: 'confirm', unlock: 'unblock', sign_up: 'sign_up', sign_out: 'logout'}
```

Comment: I get the below error: undefined method `sign_up' for #<RegistrationsController:0x00000005fddb30>

Comment: Okay I think I know your issue - you've probably got a path problem

Comment: What should I do now?

Comment: I'll post up what I think the error is - see if it fixes it

Comment: Any more errors? There are only going to be certain issues causing the problem

Comment: It says no routing defined for /users

Comment: And this when you access with a GET JSON request?

Comment: You don't have any GET routes for /users -> https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb check out the routes for Devise here

Answer (score 1):

If we run `rake routes` we can see that devise sign up (registration) has [new, create, update, ..]

```
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                 devise/registrations#cancel
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                   devise/registrations#edit
       user_registration PATCH  /users(.:format)                        devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                        devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                        devise/registrations#destroy
                         POST   /users(.:format)                        devise/registrations#create
```

So, the route `#new` shows only the sign up page and to register new user we use `#create` and **it's correct route**: `/users.json` **not** `/user/sign_up.json`

As we can see here:

```
POST   /users(.:format)                        devise/registrations#create
```

[Here's sign_up page inspect on browser, we can see action = "/users"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvXHI.png)

[routes of devise registration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLYpA.png)

Answer (score 0):

try these code ,I do it with my rails api

```
 devise_scope :user do
    post 'users' => 'registrations#create', :as => 'user_registration'
  end

 curl: //your-domain:3000/users --data "email=jump@gmail.com&password=123456789&password_confirmation=123456789"
```

Comment: I am using this curl:curl http://localhost:3000/users --data "email=jump@gmail.com&password=123456789&password_confirmation=123456789"

I get below error now: {"success":false,"info":{"email":["can't be blank"],"password":["can't be blank"]}}